# jquery addClass adding subclass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my 1st time posting here, so thanks to everyone who can give me some advice!

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <style> 

  </style> 
  <script src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div 
class="super"
style=" 
border: solid black 1px; 
height:100px;
width:100px;
">
</div> 

<div
class="super .eight"
style=" 
background: blue;
">
</div>



<script> 
  $(".super").click(function () {
      $(this).addClass(" .eight");
});
</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

So basically the problem is that I want to add for example a background or some other type of element onto class that is already defined as super. I am trying to use subclasses but it does not seem to be working.

Please ask me if there is anything unclear, I apologize if there is.

Comment: Does anybody know if there should be a dot in the class name?

Comment: Only when your refrencing it through the selector.  After that when you do addClass or removeClass you just need the class name.  Then to add more classes just add a space between class names.  Example: `$(this).addClass("eight nine");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No dot (in the classname).

```
 $(".super").click(function () { $(this).addClass("eight"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".super").click(function () { $(this).addClass("eight"); });
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out myself